# jQuery Mobile delegate vs live vs bind

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I can't seem to wrap my head around the differences between the following in jQuery Mobile:

```
$( document ).live('pageshow', function(event) {
});

$( document ).bind('pageshow', function(event) {
});

$( document ).delegate("#page", "pageshow", function() {
});
```

How do I execute scripts in the head of my documents that are DIFFERENT in certain pages? Which methods do I use to call those scripts?

Update:
jQuery version:        1.7.1
jQuery Mobile version: 1.1.0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would bind to a "page event" that jQuery Mobile exposes, like `pageinit`:

```
$(document).delegate('#my-page', 'pageinit', function () {
    //this is like document.ready for this pseudo-page
});
```

Since you're using jQuery Core 1.7.1 you can use `.on()` which has a slightly different syntax:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#my-page', function () {
    //this is like document.ready for this pseudo-page
});
```

All three of your methods do similar things. `.live()` is the same thing as using `.delegate()` with `document` as the root selection but it's been depreciated so it's a good idea to stop using it (source: http://api.jquery.com/on). Using `.bind()` directly on the `document` element is the same as using `.delegate()` but when you use `.bind()` you have to determine which pseudo-page had the event fired on it in the event handler rather than in the function call.

For example:

```
$(document).bind('pageshow', function () {
    var id = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
    //you can use $.mobile.activePage to do work on the current page
});
```

In general, event delegation is used when we don't know when an element will exist in the DOM. It relies on events bubbling up the DOM until they get to the root selection (in your case it's always the `document` element).

Docs for `.delegate()`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate

For more general information about the difference between these functions, see this article (I've read it to check it for accuracy and it's right-on): http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

Comment: Thanks for the resources. This is great. I have another somewhat related question. Let's say my homepage has a slideshow. Should I call the slideshow code within the 'pageinit' or 'pageshow' function?

Comment: `pageshow` will fire each subsequent time the user sees the page. For instance it will fire when you view the homepage for the first time, but it will also fire when you navigate away and then back to the homepage. I would setup the slideshow in the `pageinit` event handler but then stop it in the `pagehide` event handler and start it in the `pageshow` event handler. This will work for the initial load because the `pageshow` event fires after the `pageinit` event.

Comment: If I setup the slideshow (i.e. run a function to init the slideshow) in BOTH the `pageinit` and the `pageshow` event handler, wouldn't it call the function twice?

Comment: What I was saying was to initialize the slideshow (not start it) in `pageinit`, then start it in `pageshow` and stop it in `pagehide` so it's not using the CPU for no reason. I don't know what plugin you're using but normally you can initialize a slideshow without autostarting it.

Comment: Ahhh I understand. I'm using [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) right now. Can you recommend any great slideshows specifically for mobile (i.e. with touch events)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11064/discussion-between-cuserjuicer-and-jasper)

Comment: Flexslider isn't that bad. I'm using it alot with Jquery Mobile and can't complain so far :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent description: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/08/bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-function.html

But the short answer is that if you're using jquery 1.7, you should probably start using the new API on() instead of any of these: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: That article is actually confusing. For instance, `.live()` doesn't bind to the elements you're targeting (ever), it binds to the `document` element (always) and checks bubbling events for the target element to see if it matches the selection you passed into `.live()`. Also, `.live()` can be used in chaining, but the author uses a stupid example to show the opposite. Please don't use this article as the basis of your information about these functions.

Comment: Try this article, it's much better: http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question the other day and found that this article provided a clear break down on each.

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/08/bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-function.html

Comment: This article is full of invalid statements, see my comment on Julie Sheffield's answer.

Comment: Try this article, it's really a good one: http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html