# Click function not working using jquery on tablet device inside document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, tablet

I am not a JS developer, I am just a Web Designer dealing with simple JS interaction most of the time.

I am using jquery-1.11.3 and jquery.mobile v1.4.5 with just core features and slider capability.
As tablet I have a kindle with the firefox (beta) browser and an ipod with safari browser.

I am having a problem in understanding some JS behaviours of tablets and browsers regarding the click event function and document ready

```
$(function(){
  $('.menu-ham').click(function(){
    alert("test")
  });
});
```

the click event doesn't work on tablets but it works perfectly on web browsers.

Instead if use this outside the document ready

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-ham', function(){
    alert("test")
})
```

it works like a charm. Only that I am not sure if this it would create problem with the browser because not inside document.ready

I tried to use as well

```
$(function(){
  $('.menu-ham').on('click', function(){
    alert("test")
  });
});
```

inside or outside the document ready and nothing works.

"menu-ham" it is a button with that class. I read about a lot of topics, who said to use cursor:pointer, who said to use ".on('click'" instead of the normal click event, or vclick, or bind or touchstart but none really worked a part the solution that I offered, and now I am very confused about the whole thing on why is working and the other are not when I read a lot of comments that the other solution should work.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: search for event delegation in jquery.

Comment: I have read this http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ but still it is not very clear why is not working. I kept digging and I found this other answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520020/jquery-mobile-delegate-vs-live-vs-bind i understand the problem is related to delegation, but still it is not completely clear (and the link for deeper information is not working).

Comment: how are you adding elements `.menu-ham` in mobile devices?? are they being loaded after document ready??

Comment: The container of .menu-ham has .mobile class, on which detect with media query if you have the right size to show the content inside with a display:none or block. So when you are tablet it show display:block, but at the start I think by default it is display:none - I guess that you are hinting that display:none before becoming display:block is creating the problem for the document ready function to work... right? let me check it it is so

Comment: @Littlemad are you creating this button at runtime?

Comment: Sunil not understanding really the question about runtime. The button it is already in the html I am not injecting anything with js. But I guess that the display:none it might create problem with JS.

Comment: @Littlemad: i don't see the reason for this not to work if element is already there on page even if it is invisible in beginning. do check whether the elements are rendered later. you can do this by checking length of elements before binding event.

Comment: do you mean to do a $(".menu-ham").length() in a alert? (console.log doesn't show on the tablets)

Comment: Ok so display:none it is uninfluential - I ran a alert("test= "+$('.menu-ham').length); before the function and it is not working at all in the tablet if put inside document ready, but it works on the browser showing value =1. If I put it outside the document ready it give on the tablet value 0

Comment: I ran some more test, and I feel that there is a conflict between jquery mobile and document ready. But everything it is way above my head in understanding why it is so.

Comment: In jQuery Mobile, you should use one of the page events like pagecreate(http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/) instead of the regular document.ready. $(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ $('.menu-ham').on('click', function(){}) })

Comment: Thx, I was looking for solution and you are right, I did that. But now any kind of function that I used inside the document ready are not working because if I try to get any identification of any elements to apply anything they have always a $(".myClass").length = 0 of value, the page in the tablet kinda get stuck on the loading of jquery mobile, and nothing of the content is properly loaded. I start to want to rip off the mobile jquery to pieces. It just stopping me from using anything and I don't understand why it doesn't see any HTML element.

Comment: For example: $(document).delegate("#main-page", "pageinit", function(){checkSize();}); it is not working. A simple if($(".media").width() == "1"){/* max-width: 1200px */ varSize = 1;} breaks everything. The fault is the $(".myClass") functionality doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Now if I try $(document).on("pagecreate", "#main-page", function(){
 alert("test= " + $('.media').length)
});
the alert doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! it was all fault of Phalcon debugbar. On the mobile devices was generating an error that it wasn't happening on the normal browser. This error was making any jquery or selectors working.

Thank you for your help and support!